# AutoCompleteTextView cannot input second character (Nexus 5X)

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a ChildFragment which extends ParentFragment with a menu CustomView. CustomView extends LinearLayout, and this layout has an AutoCompleteTextView:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/searchId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonId"
            android:background="@null"
            android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/list_selector_bk"
            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="@dimen/margin_parts"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text|textAutoComplete|textNoSuggestions"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/actionbar_cursor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal" />
```

When I input second character in AutoCompleteTextView, onclick event of ChildFragment is called. Please help me find this problem. Thanks a lot.

Updated:

```
class ChildFragment extends ParentFragment implements View.OnClickListener, DialogActionCallback {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Show ABC dialog
    }
}

class HideFragment extends Fragment implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener, OnPrepareOptionsMenuListener, OnOptionsItemSelectedListener {
    // Override methods
}

class ParentFragment extends HideFragment implements State, BaseInterface,
        DialogConst, OnDialogResultListener {
    protected CustomView customView;

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        customView = (CustomView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_menu_search).getActionView();
    }
}

action_menu_search.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/btn_com_search_selector"
        android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="xxx.CustomView"
        android:title="@string/action_menu_title_search"
        android:titleCondensed="@string/action_menu_title_search">
    </item>
    ....
</menu>

class CustomView extends LinearLayout implements MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener,
        View.OnClickListener, TextWatcher, View.OnKeyListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener,
        SearchController.Callback, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {

    private AutoCompleteTextView customView;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        // layout = load layout contains AutoCompleteTextView 
        customView = (AutoCompleteTextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.searchId);
        customView.setOnKeyListener(this);
        customView.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        customView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        customView.setThreshold(0);
        customView.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(mContext.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.bg_color_dark_gray)));
        customView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Hide/show suggest dialog
    }

}
```

Purpose is show suggest dialog when input character in autocompleteview. But this bug is found on Nexus 5x when input second character quickly, and ABC dialog is showing instead of suggest dialog. No problem for many device. Sorry for my expression. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Post your code, otherwise its hard to understand

Comment: I have just updated my post, sorry and thanks.

Comment: I think that AutoCompleteTextView is lost focus after typed first character. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found my solution:

If suggestion list no data
setDropDownHeight(1);
Else
setDropDownHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

But I don't know why?